# Вывод значения при выборе элемента списка

Tags: php, sql

Есть база данных на sql. Я на php написала программу, которая выводит таблицы, выводит с 1-й таблицы в выпадающем списке veshestvo. Если выбираешь veshestvo из выпадающего списка, у него определёная opasnost. Например, мы выбираем Azodikarbonat, opasnost 3 (по таблице). Тогда при нажатии кнопки Prob K_3=K3 (из 2-й табл). Если opasnost у нас 3, соотвественно какое veshestvo мы выбрали, то по 2-й таблице Clas 3 и K3 берём по 3 Clas. То есть veshestvo выбрали Azodikarbonat, то opasnost 3, Clas 3 и тогда K3=2.30.

> `EC_16 = pdk_sred_sutoch, C = pdk_max_raz` (соответствено тому, какое veshestvo мы выбрали)
> `GDK = EC_16 / K_3;`

И тогда при нажатии кнопки Prob вычисляется:

> `Prob = -5.51 + 0.49 * Math.Log10(C / GDK);`

Таблица 1-я:

> `no    veshestvo   pdk_sred_sutoch  pdk_max_raz    pokazat         opasnost`
> `1  Aziridin    0.0005           0.0010         rez.            1`
> `2  Azodikarbonat   0.3000           0.5000         refl.-rez.  3`
> `Таблица 2-я :`
> `Clas   K3`
> `1  5.00`
> `2  4.00`
> `3  2.30`
> `4  1.50`
> `Таблица 3-я :`
> `Risk   Prob`
> `-3.00  0.0010`
> `-2.50  0.0060`
> `-2.00  0.0230`
> `-1.90  0.0290`
> `-1.80  0.0360`
> `-1.70  0.0450`
> `-1.60  0.0550`
> `-1.40  0.0810`
> `Таблица 4-я :`
> `Clas   K_3 b`
> `1  7.50    2.35`
> `2  6.00    1.28`
> `3  4.50    1.00`
> `4  3.00    0.87`

Вот программа

```
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<form name="form">
<?php
    /* Соединяемся, выбираем базу данных */
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root")
        or die("Could not connect : " . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("risk") or die("Could not select database");
function is_sel($a, $field)
{
  $b = isset($_POST[$field])?$_POST[$field]:NULL;
  if($a == $b) return 'selected="selected"';
}

    /* Выполняем SQL-запрос */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM list1";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

    /* Выводим результаты в html */
     print "<table>";
    // $optionlist = '';
     $p=1;
     $s=1;
     $c=1;
     $v=1;
     echo"<table border=1>";
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {// вставляем код сюда (потому что здесь же будет верх таблицы, правильно?)
    if ($p == 1) 
        {
    echo"<tr>";
foreach ($line as $ind =>$zn){echo"<td>$ind</td>";}// выводим названия столбцов
        echo"</tr>";
        $p=2; // присваиваем переменной $p двойку, чтоб при следующей итерации цикла while не выводились названия столбцов $ind
        }
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($line as $zn){echo"<td>$zn</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
       }echo"</table>";
      /* Выполняем SQL-запрос */
    $quer = "SELECT * FROM klas";
    $resul = mysql_query($quer) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

    /* Выводим результаты в html */
    print "<table>"; 
    echo"<table border=1>";
      while ($lin = mysql_fetch_array($resul, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
    if ($s == 1) 
        {
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($lin as $ind =>$zn){echo"<td>$ind</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
        $s=2; // присваиваем переменной $p двойку, чтоб при следующей итерации цикла while не выводились названия столбцов $ind
        }
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($lin as $zn){echo"<td>$zn</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
    }
       echo"</table>";
       /* Выполняем SQL-запрос */
    $quer1 = "SELECT * FROM Prob";
    $resul1 = mysql_query($quer1) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

    /* Выводим результаты в html */
    print "<table>"; 
    echo"<table border=1>";
      while ($lin1 = mysql_fetch_array($resul1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
    if ($c == 1) 
        {
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($lin1 as $ind =>$zn){echo"<td>$ind</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
        $c=2; // присваиваем переменной $p двойку, чтоб при следующей итерации цикла while не выводились названия столбцов $ind
        }
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($lin1 as $zn){echo"<td>$zn</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
    }
       echo"</table>";
       /* Выполняем SQL-запрос */
    $quer2 = "SELECT * FROM A_2";
    $resul2 = mysql_query($quer2) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

    /* Выводим результаты в html */
    print "<table>"; 
    echo"<table border=1>";
      while ($lin2 = mysql_fetch_array($resul2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
    {
    if ($v == 1) 
        {
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($lin2 as $ind =>$zn){echo"<td>$ind</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
        $v=2; // присваиваем переменной $p двойку, чтоб при следующей итерации цикла while не выводились названия столбцов $ind
        }
        echo"<tr>";
        foreach ($lin2 as $zn){echo"<td>$zn</td>";}
        echo"</tr>";
    }
       echo"</table>";
       $query = "SELECT veshestvo,opasnost from  list1";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    echo "<select  >";
     $optionlist = '';
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
          {
                if($_POST['veshestvo'] == $line['veshestvo'])
                {
                $selected = "selected";
                }
                echo "<option value=$line[veshestvo] $selected> $line[veshestvo]</option>";
   echo "</select><br><br>";
 echo"</table>";
  /* Освобождаем память от результата */
    mysql_free_result($result);
 /* Закрываем соединение */
    mysql_close($link);
?>
      <tr>

      <br> <th width="150"><input type="submit" value="Prob" style="text-align:center; font-size:11px; font-family: Tahoma; background-color: #F0F0F0; border-width: 1; border-style: solid; border-color:#284465; color: #006699">   
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <br>  <th width="150"><input type="submit" value="Риск" style="text-align:center; font-size:11px; font-family: Tahoma; background-color: #F0F0F0; border-width: 1; border-style: solid; border-color:#284465; color: #006699">
      </tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Как это сделать? Или хотя бы подскажите, как сделать, чтоб при выборе veshestvo выводилось её opasnost и из 2-й таблицы выводилось Clas K3 соотвественно какая opasnost. (Если opasnost=3 Clas=3)

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял смысл данных в таблицах, то все вычисления можно сделать еще на этапе выборки в одном SQL-запросе и для всех значений, объединив 1-ю и 2-ю таблицы по полям *opasnost* и *Clas*:

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    t2.K3,
    ( t1.pdk_sred_sutoch / t2.K3 ) AS GDK,
    ( -5.51 + 0.49 * LOG10(t1.pdk_max_raz / (t1.pdk_sred_sutoch / t2.K3)) ) AS Prob
FROM `Таблица 1-я` t1
LEFT JOIN `Таблица 2-я` t2 ON t2.Clas = t1.opasnost
```

Он выведет все поля таблицы 1, плюс, соответствующие *K3* из таблицы 2. А, также, в отдельных колонках, посчитает *GDK* и *Prob*.
Не стал оптимизировать мат-выражения чтобы было понятно что и где подставляется.

На всякий случай: в запрос вместо `Таблица 1-я` и `Таблица 2-я` нужно подставить реальные названия таблиц.